# Bootstrap 3 form Alignment

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment, bootstrapping

I am using Bootstrap 3, what I want cover whole form on full page like attached image, in the image I am using kendo UI popup window. pop up window width is 1000px

Here is my HTML code,

```
<section class="container-fluid padding-rl">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
         <div class="profile-box">
             <img class="profile-picture" src="" alt="" />
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="form-horizontal">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-1">First Name:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedRecord.FirstName" />
                     </div>
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">Last Name:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedRecord.LastName" />
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">

                     <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Email:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-3" style="">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedRecord.Email" />
                     </div>
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 ">Mobile:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-3" style="">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedRecord.Mobile" />
                     </div>

                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">

                     <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Phone:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-3" style="">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedRecord.OfficePhone" />
                     </div>

                     <label class="control-label col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 ">Account:</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-3" style="">
                         <input type="text" id="txtContactAccount" class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedRecord.ContactAccount" />
                     </div>

                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Attached image [image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please share the link for this?

Comment: Added Code Ahsan Aziz

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't see your code in your question.  From the sample picture I'm guessing what you are looking to do is create a modal?

Take a look at bootstrap's documentation here:
[Bootstrap JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Scroll down a bit to the part about modals, they have nice samples there too.

Comment: Reading the question a few more times and now that he has added his html (still missing css, unless has none other than bootstrap) I'm thinking the question might be simply how to align his form with the right edge of the modal, or have the form span 100% of the desired modal area.

Comment: Should be just a matter of one or two css overrides

Comment: or maybe he wants the actual modal to come close in fiilling the entire window space, like setting 90% width to it....